# Sum values from list of dicts in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a JSON like this. I am trying to add up the counter values at each level and add to the parent node but couldn't achieve this.

```
{"sample": {
    "counter": "Not defined",
    "children": [
            {
                "counter": "Not Defined",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "counter": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "counter": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "counter": "Not Defined",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "counter": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "counter": 20
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried using pandas

```
final_json = (pd.DataFrame(json['sample'])
   .groupby(['counter'], as_index=False)
   .Flow.sum()
   .to_dict('r'))
```

and also tried

```
result = dict(functools.reduce(operator.add, 
         map(collections.Counter, json)))
```

but couldn't quite get it.

My output should look like the following

```
{"sample": {
    "counter": 80
    "children": [
        {
            "counter": 40
            "children": [
                {
                    "counter": 20
                },
                {
                    "counter": 20
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "counter": 40
            "children": [
                {
                    "counter": 20
                },
                {
                    "counter": 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Is the number of levels arbitrary?

Comment: yea. they will be arbitrary. but the key names gonna be the same name with counter